# PHP array(3,5,6,7,8,11) how do we know the missing values are 1,2,4,9,10

Tags: php

I got a an array like this $ids = array(3,7,6,5,1,8,11) . How do we know the missing values are 2,4,9,10 ?

My expecting $ids values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 and order doesn't matter, it could be 3,5,6,1,2,4,8,9,10,11.

I don't need to fill my array with the missing values I just want to know who's missing

Comment: why isn't 12 a missing value? what about 0? -1?

Comment: missing values are 2,4,9,10 there is no 0 and -1 as well as 12 in the missing values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$numbers = array(3,5,6,7,8,11);

$missing = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < max($numbers); $i++) {
    if (!in_array($i, $numbers)) $missing[] = $i;
}

print_r($missing); //1,4,9,10
```

Answer (score 28):

Here's nice one-liner:

```
$ids = array(3,5,6,7,8,11);
$missing = array_diff(range(1, max($ids)), $ids);
```

Comment: *sigh* I didn't even think to create the range array on the fly like that (see my answer)... That's it, I'm definitely going to bed now.

Comment: @Petah: Yes, but the first line was a restatement of the code in the question. The second line is the solution. :-P Cut me some slack!

Comment: Just wanted to add that this answer saved me a ton of trouble. I have a list of numbers up to 100,000 and need a list of unused numbers. Going the usual route of counting through them all took 190 seconds... Tried `array_diff` just as it was in this answer, and it took 2 seconds :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sort of a poorly defined question, but I'll bite.

Why not grab the lowest (`min()`) and highest (`max()`) values in the array, then walk through the array in a for loop, adding missing values to a second array as they're found?

On second thought, there's an even better way: you could preload the second array `using range()`, passing in the low/high values from the first and last indexes, then use `array_diff_key()` to find the missing values.

This is all assuming I've understood your question correctly, and you just want to fill in missing values using the already defined array to define the boundaries.

Comment: You don't need to sort, you can use `max` and `min` to get the largest and smallest values in an array

Comment: @Dan This is what I get for stacking at 3am when I should be in bed. I just came here to look something up, but somehow got caught up answering. I'll edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I had to double check that PHP has a function to get the `max` and `min` of an array myself :)

Comment: @Dan: Of course it does! I'm pretty sure PHP has a `kitchen_sink()` function too...

Answer (score -1):

```
$ids = array(3,7,6,5,1,8,11);
//var_dump(max($array));
$arr        = range(1,max($ids));
$missing    =   array_diff($arr,$ids);
var_dump($missing);
```